# Can R be used as the main platform for an enterprise application?

Tags: rstudio, platform

Is R suitable as a main application platform?

My understanding is that R is used mainly for functionality related to statistics and data-science. 
A member of our team is suggesting to consider R as the main platform for a planned application, as opposed to Java or Node.Js. The application has some data-science functionality.

Would appreciate if you'd share related insights.

Comment: You can use `Shiny` in order to get reports in a web fashion...it depends on the scope of what you want to build...

Comment: Thank you @Hackerman.

An example of what I'm not clear about is how good can R handle things like backend, database access, business logic, etc. I mean functionality that is traditionally done by Java, C#, etc. 
Can R effectively/ efficiently replace/ substitute those platforms ?